# Android Studio Build Error - NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting below error on building the project.

```
NEGOTIATE authentication error: Invalid name provided (Mechanism level: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm)
```

I tried adding proxy in gradle.properties but that doesn't work.

```
systemProp.http.proxyPort=
systemProp.http.proxyUser=
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=
systemProp.https.proxyHost=
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=
systemProp.https.proxyPort=
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=
systemProp.https.proxyUser=
```

Any solution for this?